# Count how many times number entered until the first symmetry number is entered

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code but only works when the first number is symmetry:

symmetry is like this number: 4554 (reading from both ends is the same number)

My question is why the break only works for the first number? It happens when I run it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=0, z=0, r=0, x=0, m;
    for (;;) {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> x;
        m = x;

        while(x!=0) {
            r = x % 10;
            z = z * 10 + r;
            x = x / 10;
        }
        if(m==z)
            break;
        else
            n++;
    }
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good job, nice code.....what's your problem actually?

Comment: Would be cool to know the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move int z=0, r=0; inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this code to know if the number is symmetry?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    for (;;) {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> x;
        m = x;

        std::stringstream str;
        str << x;

        std::string number = str.str();
        if ( number == std::string( number.rbegin(), number.rend() )
            break;
        else
            n++;
    }
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Simpler, leads to the same result and is definitely more error prone ;-)

Comment: This is most likely an assignment.

Comment: @SergeyA: Sure....but it does not mean you have to manipulate numbers (except if OP posts the assignment constraints....). It looks more elegant to me and definitely easier to understand what the code does.....Teacher will be definitely surprised by the answer, but could accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been much easier to reason if you have written like this:

```
#include <iostream>

bool isPalindrome(int x)
{
    int y = x;
    int z;
    while (x) {
        z = z * 10 + x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return y == z;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int x;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> x;
        if (isPalindrome(x))
            break;
        else
            ++n;
    }
    std::out << "Number of non-palindromes: " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

functions with meaningful names always helpful!